# Динамический запрос на создание таблицы

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть поле, куда вводится количество полей, которое необходимо сгенерировать.
С помощью JS создаются . Первое поле - это название поля, второе поля - тип данных.

```
      function add(){
var input = document.querySelector("input[name='number_rs']"), log = document.querySelector('p');
            if( /\D/.test( input.value ) ) {
                alert('В поле должны быть только цифры');
            return; }
            if(input.value & 1) {
                $("#success").text("Введите чётное число");
                return;
            }

            var i = 0, j = 0;

            var g = document.createDocumentFragment();
            var q = document.createDocumentFragment();

            var m, br, z;

            while( i++ < parseInt( input.value ) ){
                br = document.createElement('br');
                m =  document.createElement('input');
                z =  document.createElement('input');
                if(j==2) {
                    g.appendChild(br);
                    j = 0;
                }
                m.name = 'text'+i;
                g.appendChild(m);
                m.name = 'text'+i+1;
                g.appendChild(m);
j++;
             }

            g.appendChild(br);
            log.innerHTML = '';
            log.appendChild( g );
            log.appendChild( q );

        }
```

После их заполнения по нажатию на кнопку данные из сгенерированных полей отправляются на обработку в php файл. 
Часть кода, где генерируются поля.

```
<label>Сколько полей создать?</label>
    <input type="text" name="number_rs" onkeyup="add();"><br>
    <label>Название поля</label> <label style="margin-left: 80px">Тип поля</label>
    <form action="create_table.php" method = "post">
        <p name = "data"></p>
        <input type = submit id = "send"><br>
    </form>
```

Стоит задача составить запрос на создание новой таблицы на основе введённых данных. В таблицу заносится название полей и их типы.
Пытался сделать сам.

```
 <?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost",'root', "", "andrey") or die("Ошибка подключения");
$query="create table test3"."(";
$j=1;
$first_part = "";
$second_part = "";
for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {

    $first_part= $_POST['text' . $i . '1'] . " ";
    $sql.=$first_part;

    $i++;

    $second_part = $_POST['text' . $i . '1'];
    $sql.=" ".$second_part.",";

    echo "<br>";


}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);

$sql.=")";
$query.=$sql;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
```

Как передать количество созданных полей для использования в цикле?
Подойдут любые идеи. Спасибо.

Comment: Я отредактировал php код. Запросы работают как надо. Но теперь нужно как-то передать количество сгенерированных полей, чтобы использовать их в цикле.

Comment: `count($POST)`?

Comment: Боже, точно. Я совсем забыл, что у $_post есть count. Спасибо, что напомнили)

Comment: <зануда_моде>у $_POST нет count, count просто есть, и может считать все, что угодно, в т.ч. $_POST</зануда_моде>

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь.